# jpa criteria builder combine pagination and count results

Tags: jpa, count, pagination, eclipselink, criteria

implementing pagination you can use criteria builder to return a page out of a result-set. However, if you need to get the full number of results (pages) you have to run a separate query with the same criteria for the count.

is there a way to combine the two together into single database call and save on performance without returning the full set and implement the page yourself?

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<EntityJpa> cq = cb.createQuery(EntityJpa.class);
    Root<EntityJpa> root = cq.from(EntityJpa.class);
    Predicate p = cb.conjunction();
    cq.where(p);
    TypedQuery<EntityJpa> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
    return tq.getResultList();
```

AND the count

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<EntityJpa> r = cq.from(EntityJpa.class);
    Predicate p = cb.conjunction();
    cq.where(p);
    cq.select(cb.count(r));
    TypedQuery<Long> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
    return tq.getSingleResult().intValue();
```

Comment: Do you ask how to perform pagination manually (e.g. if the result set is small)? If you fetch all results from the DB the count would simply be `tq.getResultList().size()`. I'm pretty sure I'm missing the point here...

Comment: Thanks @Robin . no, our data-set can have millions of records. I am asking if there is a way to get the full query count and the page at the same time.

Comment: Ok now I understand, you want to save one db roundtrip while doing pagination.  
I don't think this is possible using JPA since there's no SQL standard for this nor do all the major databases provide support for this kind of query. But I may be wrong, I would like to learn about a solution, too!

Comment: I recently found that spring-boot-data-jpa support this. I need to dig in the code to find out how exactly this is implemented

Answer (score 0):

```
CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
cq.select(cb.count(root)).where(pred).distinct(true);
Long maxPages = em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
```

We Utilize something like this.  I am working on a way to cache the results so I don't have to run the count every time it is paged, but this is working for us right now.